# Error code = 0x80070002 (MS Visual Studio) C++ for searching triplet data from one key element

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, path-finding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AopK6.jpg)

How finding a map triplet pair with one element for example 
(4,(?,?))
so i know that int 4 -> how can i find it because i get so much error and four hours of searching for possible solution to filter the coordinates with that key.

```
 int k = *min_element(min1.begin(), min1.end());

 auto it = myninja.begin(); 
 it = find(myninja.begin(), myninja.end(), k);
 for (it = myninja.begin(); it != myninja.end(); it++) {
     p.row= (it->second).first;
     p.col = (it->second).second;
 }
```

these are my declarations

```
vector <pair<int, pair<int, int> > > myninja; 
    vector <int> min1;
```

and this is where i want to put out my min for A* -> f value for minimum range to goal

```
 int k = *min_element(min1.begin(), min1.end());
```

to keep the actual value from this i want to update the start point with the minimum of f -> so i want to give the point (x,y) so i thought

```
vector <pair<int, pair<int, int> > > myninja;
```

would be the best, but always i want to find out from which f(n) value it comes from -> error in iterator/loop or it displays me errorcode

i think i comes from the find function because maybe he can't handle a int k (which i want to search my points)

(F-Value,(x-coordinate,y-coordinate)

also this is not working

```
int k = *min_element(min1.begin(), min1.end());
auto result = std::find_if(myninja.begin(),myninja.end(),[k](const auto& mo){return mo.second == val; });

 //RETURN VARIABLE IF FOUND
  if (result != myninja.end())
  int foundkey = (result->second).first;
```

Comment: Strange, error code 8007002 is a [Windows Update Error Code](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-updates-error-code-80070002/d1d47f2b-d638-4d67-850d-45b074120949).

Comment: sure that is a update ?

Comment: Search the internet with the error code.  See what comes up.

Comment: i don't know, why i can't searching for that 
vector <pair<int,pair<int,int>>> myninja; 
i got always error and tried other ways of finding that kind of pair (4,(?,?))
am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    int s = myninja.size();
    int j = min1.size(); 
      
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
    min1.push_back(myninja[i].first);
    }
    
    int mic = min1[0];
    
    for (int i = 0; i <j; i++)
     {
     if (min1[i] < mic)
     mic = min1[i];
     }
    
     cout << mic;
     
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
    if (myninja[i].first == mic) {
    
    // "first" and "second" are used to access 
    // 1st and 2nd element of pair respectively 
    
    p.row = myninja[i].second.first;
    p.col = myninja[i].second.second;
    
    q.push(objects(p.row, p.col, p.dist+1));
    
    cout << "Min Punkt";
    cout << " x " << p.row << " y " << p.col;
    
    cout << "Distanz"; 
    cout << p.dist;
    
    visit[p.row][p.col] = true;
    break;
}      
}
```

// Finally it works but it saves now the same point again and again with the minimum of f.
// i am working on to delete or set it true so after the calculation -> get the new point with other f minimum till the goal.